# Java Object array to Javascript Object Array as parameter

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, json

How can I send an Java array of objects to a javascript function?

this is my object

```
class SitioMapa{
    String title;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    String description;

    public SitioMapa(String title,double lat,double lng,String description) {
        this.title=title;
        this.lat=lat;
        this.lng=lng;
        this.description=description;       
    }
}
```

Passing to JSon it looks like

```
"SitioMapa":[{"title":"Alibaug","lat":"18.641400","lng":"72.872200","description": "Alibaug is a coastal town and a municipal council in Raigad District in the Konkan region of Maharashtra, India."},{...},{...}]
```

I send a SitioMapa[] array filled with objects like above to a function in javascript, but i need conevrt the array in something lie this

```
var markers = [
        {
            "title": 'Alibaug',
            "lat": '18.641400',
            "lng": '72.872200',
            "description": 'Alibaug is a coastal town and a municipal council in Raigad District in the Konkan region of Maharashtra, India.'
        }
    ,
        {
            "title": 'Mumbai',
            "lat": '18.964700',
            "lng": '72.825800',
            "description": 'Mumbai formerly Bombay, is the capital city of the Indian state of Maharashtra.'
        }
    ,
        {
            "title": 'Pune',
            "lat": '18.523600',
            "lng": '73.847800',
            "description": 'Pune is the seventh largest metropolis in India, the second largest in the state of Maharashtra after Mumbai.'
        }
];
```

How can i do this?

I have tried JsonObject and JsonArray but still show the parameter like 1 Object array and can´t access to the data in the array.

Comment: Why not just use `yourObject.SitioMapa`, this should give you the array.

Comment: This may be helpful for java + json : https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

Comment: I don´t get it. I have an array in a java code    
`SitioMapa [] sitios;`


load url in

    `public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
 view.loadUrl("javascript:window.onload("+sitios+")");
 }`

In the webview a try to log the content of the array and it shows

    `[object Event]`

Comment: Please post your entire javascript code that calls the java method.

Comment: `window.onload = function (prueba) {
    
    for(i=0;i<prueba.length;i++){
    alert(prueba[i]);
  }
`

im just trying to log the data, it doesn´t work

Comment: `SitioMapa prueba[]=new SitioMapa[3];

prueba[0]=new SitioMapa("Alibaug",18.641400,72.872200,"description test");

prueba[1]=new SitioMapa(....`

I verified the array in java code, it is fine

`onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {  view.loadUrl("javascript:window.onload("+prueba+")");  }`

this is the loadurl code

Answer (score 0):

Refer [How To Convert Java Object To / From JSON (Gson) MKYong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/).